# TimerTick wont trigger ever

Tags: c#, class, timer, task

I've created simple class which will behave like my service class, because I've included that class in Topshelf.

Class is simple it just imports some files to db and prints it after it.

Here is the definition:

```
class ConverterService
{
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    private readonly System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public ConverterService()
    {
        ImportAllFiles();

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10){AutoReset = true};
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintFiles();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

But problem is `Timer_Elapsed` is never executed..
I don't know why..

`ImportAllFiles()` triggers successfully but `Timer_Elapsed` method is never fired, and I wanted to execute that method every second for example

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call timer `Start()`:

```
timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10){AutoReset = true};
timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
timer.Start();
```

or alternative :

```
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter because literally all `Start()` does is set `Enabled = true`.